# Al desplegar Front React Js con Render, aparece el error Can't resolve 'styled-components' en carpeta dist

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

Estoy tratando de desplegar un proyecto full stack con React, Node y PostgreSQL en Render, y al tratar de desplegar el front end me arroja un error relacionado con el módulo *styled-components* en la ruta */opt/render/project/src/front_end/node_modules/react-data-table-component/dist*.

No entiendo por qué *dist*, si la carpeta es *build*. Aunque tampoco sé si tenga que ver en el front end hay un componente que maneja un datatable que llama información del back end y este de la BD.

Esta es la información de los logs de Render:

```
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  Failed to compile.
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'styled-components' in '/opt/render/project/src/front_end/node_modules/react-data-table-component/dist'
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  npm ERR! errno 1
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  npm ERR! front_end@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  npm ERR! Exit status 1
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  npm ERR!
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  npm ERR! Failed at the front_end@0.1.0 build script.
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-11-27T04_27_40_661Z-debug.log
Nov 26 10:27:40 PM  ==> Build failed
```

Comment: No olvides mostrar el _package.json_. Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.